# Jtree: set backgroundColor to maximum single double clicked node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

On double click I high light the background of the double clicked Jtree node into Green. When I double click on other nodes, the previously selected green node should be restored to it's original and the newly double clicked node should light up green.

It's working somewhat but behaves inconsistently. When I double click children nodes, they will turn green and the previous double clicked node stays green until I select that node and select another node....

here's my custom renderer.

```
 public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer{


        public MyRenderer() {
        }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(
                        JTree tree,
                        Object value,
                        boolean sel,
                        boolean expanded,
                        boolean leaf,
                        int row,
                        boolean hasFocus) {

        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
                        tree, value, sel,
                        expanded, leaf, row,
                        hasFocus);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
        NodePro np = (NodePro)(node.getUserObject());

        if(np.getNodeancestors() != null){
            if(np.getNodeancestors().contains("activated")){
                setBackgroundNonSelectionColor(Color.GREEN);

            }else{
                setBackgroundNonSelectionColor(null);

            }
        }else{
            setBackgroundNonSelectionColor(null);

        }

        return this;
    }


}
```

Here's my Jtree which adds the double click listener.

```
  public class Tree extends JTree{
        private static Tree INSTANCE;
        private TreeSelectionListenerClass tsl;
        private TreePopupTriggerListener ptl;
        private TreeDoubleClickListener dbll;

        public Tree() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

                tsl = new TreeSelectionListenerClass();
                dbll = new TreeDoubleClickListener();

        addTreeSelectionListener(tsl);
        addMouseListener(dbll);
        setToggleClickCount(0);
        setCellRenderer(new MyRenderer());

    }
```

here's where I catch teh double click....

```
public class TreeDoubleClickListener implements MouseInputListener {

    public TreeDoubleClickListener(){

    }

    /*On Double Click (This Node Will Be Activated), Save To Activated Node */
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if (e.getClickCount() == 2){            
            Global.showWaitCursor();

            try{
                DefaultMutableTreeNode selected = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) Global.previousTreePath.getLastPathComponent();
                NodePro npx = (NodePro) selected.getUserObject();
                npx.setNodeancestors("");

                 TreePath path = Tree.getInstance().getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
                  if (path != null){                  
                      Global.previousTreePath = path;
                      DefaultMutableTreeNode current = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) Global.previousTreePath.getLastPathComponent();
                      NodePro npt = (NodePro) current.getUserObject();
                      npt.setNodeancestors("activated");
                  }

            }catch(Exception zxcv){
                //save this path to edit later
                  TreePath path = Tree.getInstance().getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
                  if (path != null){                  
                      Global.previousTreePath = path;
                      DefaultMutableTreeNode current = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) Global.previousTreePath.getLastPathComponent();
                      NodePro npt = (NodePro) current.getUserObject();
                      npt.setNodeancestors("activated");
                  }
            }


}

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also.. what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

besides changing the state of the node, you have to notify the model about the change. Assuming the model is of type DefaultTreeModel (with a custom model, you'll need to message the appropriate methods)

```
 // change node/user object
 DefaultMutableTreeNode current = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) 
          Global.previousTreePath.getLastPathComponent();
 NodePro npt = (NodePro) current.getUserObject();
 npt.setNodeancestors("activated");
 // notify model
 JTree tree = (JTree) e.getSource();
 ((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel()).nodeChanged(current);
```